# phpmailer SMTP connect() failed on localhost

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm running php5.6 on a localhost using xampp, and I'm trying to send a message using phpmailer, but it gives me this error : SMTP connect() failed.
Here's my code:

```
require("Photo Gallery/includes/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();  
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Username = "aldemeery@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "*********";
$mail->From     = "aldemeery@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress("aldemeery@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject  = "Subject";
$mail->Body     = "Hi!";
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo 'Message was not sent.';
    echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
```

I know there are tens of questions out there having the same title, but believe me none of them worked for me.Please help, I'v been trying to solve this all day long!

Comment: Did you turn on SMTP in Gmail?

Comment: yes i did turn it on

Comment: Despite the fact that nearly all of said answers will point you at [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) which tells you how to diagnose and solve exactly this kind of problem. You've also based your code on an obsolete example.

Answer (score 1):

check your antivirus apps, in my case "Avast Anti Virus" block it. then when i disabled it, the error gone.

Answer (score 0):

OK...so i'v made some changes to php.ini, my gmail account, and my PHP script...and then everything worked just fine....so here is what i changed:

- In php.ini: I removed the semicolon in front of **"sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost"** and restarted xampp.
- In my gmail account: in the [security settings](https://myaccount.google.com/security), I turned on **"Allow less secure apps"**.
- And finally in my PHP script: I added two functions:

  - **"date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC')"**
  - **"gethostbyname('ssl://smtp.gmail.com')"** as a value for **" $mail->Host"**

And here is my modified php script

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = gethostbyname('ssl://smtp.gmail.com');
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "***********";
$mail->setFrom('username@gmail.com', 'First Last');
$mail->addAddress('username@yahoo.com', 'First Last');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```